# Falar "fora à parte" está errado porque seria redundante igual "subir para cima"?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Por exemplo, na frase "você vai ter que pagar fora à parte" eu poderia estar me referindo a um pagamento fora do orçamento. Porém, se "à parte" significa algo que está fora, escrever "fora" antes de "à parte" não seria redundante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frase completa é "você vai ter que pagar fora à parte"?  Ou teria um complemento do tipo "você vai ter que pagar, fora a parte que me cabe"?  Caso seja a primeira opção, eu não entendo como sendo redundante.  Entendo como errado do ponto de vista semântico. Eu nunca ouvi alguém dizer "fora à parte" como expressão.  Mas encontrei a seguinte explicação no site da [Professora Manuka](http://www.professoramanuka.com.br/2017/09/a-parte-e-aparte-quando-usar-cada-um.html)

> **Fora à parte é uma expressão equivocada**
>
> Muitas pessoas usam a expressão fora à parte como sinônimo de separado ou não incluído, como no exemplo: “Vamos fazer as marmitas, mas o valor das quentinhas de alumínio é fora à parte.”
>
> Para escrever a sentença corretamente, seria melhor usar:
>
> - “Vamos fazer as marmitas, mas o valor das quentinhas de alumínio é à parte.”
> - “Vamos fazer as marmitas, mas o valor das quentinhas de alumínio é cobrado por fora.”

Comment: Sim, seria a primeira frase. A segunda frase, você usou "a parte" que precisa de um complemento e usando "à parte" eu já vi as pessoas usarem pra evitar falar muito, uma simplificação. Mas as duas querem dizer a mesma coisa. De qualquer modo, o texto da professora Manuka e a sua resposta resolveu o meu problema, era isso que eu queria saber.